# implement automatic Slideshow with retrieved images from database in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

This is on of the task given by my school. am totally new to angularjs. in this case am trying to implement automatic Slideshow with retrieved images from database in angularjs. i dont know how to do this.please help me. i tried multiple tutorials but all of those did not worked for me.

this is my angular controller.

```
appGM.controller('bannerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'urls', function ($scope, $http, urls) {
var request = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: urls.api + 'Banner/LeftBanner'

}).success(function (data, status) {

    console.log(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));

    $scope.BottomBanner = angular.fromJson(data);

})
 .error(function (error) {
     $scope.status = 'Unable to load dog images: ' + error.message;
     console.log($scope.status);
 });
```

my HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav" ng-repeat="d in BottomBanner">
                        <img ng-src="{{d.bottomBannerPath}}">
    </div>
```

this my json:

```
{
    "bottomBannerId": 1,
    "bottomBannerPath": "Content/Banner/banner.jpg",
    "bottomBannerLocation": 2
  },
  {
    "bottomBannerId": 2,
    "bottomBannerPath": "Content/Banner/banner1.jpg",
    "bottomBannerLocation": 2
  },
  {
    "bottomBannerId": 3,
    "bottomBannerPath": "Content/Banner/banner2.jpg",
    "bottomBannerLocation": 2
  },
  {
    "bottomBannerId": 4,
    "bottomBannerPath": "Content/Banner/banner3.jpg",
    "bottomBannerLocation": 2
  },
  {
    "bottomBannerId": 5,
    "bottomBannerPath": "Content/Banner/banner4.jpg",
    "bottomBannerLocation": 2
  },
  {
    "bottomBannerId": 6,
    "bottomBannerPath": "Content/Banner/banner5.jpg",
    "bottomBannerLocation": 2
  }
]
```

This what i exactly needed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **reusable** **`Directive`** I created to achieve your functionality, **simple and without any use of external plugins**

**I made is so simple that, I only changed the `src attribute` of the image tag dynamically using `$interval`**

```
function updateTime() {
  attrs.$set('src',scope.images[i].image);
  i ++
  if(i == scope.images.length)
  {
    i = 0
  }
}

var i = 0;
stopTime = $interval(updateTime, 500);
```

Here is the important part of code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-interval-service-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="intervalExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('intervalExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interval',
      function($scope, $interval) {
        
        $scope.images = [{
    image: "http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131121235548/leagueoflegends/images/d/d5/Executioner_mastery_s3.png",
    currentPoint: "0",
    endPoint: "1"
  }, {
    image: "http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131121235640/leagueoflegends/images/e/e9/Fury_mastery_s4.png",
    currentPoint: "0",
    endPoint: "4"
  }, {
    image: "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131121235650/leagueoflegends/images/f/f5/Sorcery_mastery_s4.png",
    currentPoint: "0",
    endPoint: "4"
  }, {
    image: "http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131121235724/leagueoflegends/images/5/58/Butcher_mastery_s4.png",
    currentPoint: "0",
    endPoint: "1"
  }]
    
      }])
    
    .directive('myImages', ['$interval', 'dateFilter',
      function($interval, dateFilter) {
        // return the directive link function. (compile function not needed)
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    
          function updateTime() {
            attrs.$set('src',scope.images[i].image);
            i ++
            if(i == scope.images.length)
            {
              i = 0
            }
          }

          // watch the expression, and update the UI on change.
          
          var i = 0;
          stopTime = $interval(updateTime, 500);

          // listen on DOM destroy (removal) event, and cancel the next UI update
          // to prevent updating time after the DOM element was removed.
          element.on('$destroy', function() {
            $interval.cancel(stopTime);
          });
        }
      }]);
</script>

<div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
       <img my-images images="images"/>
    <hr/>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above code**

(OR)

[Here is a working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oJiMUxTPSzXSLDEtpC2e?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your comment brother. anyhow am new to the angular. in this case how can i implement these into my codes??

Comment: add `<img my-images images="BottomBanner"/>` this into your html file, add the directive into `js` file using your model, and change `scope.images[i].image` to `scope.images[i].bottomBannerPath` and make sure `bottomBannerPath` is a URL